# Issue with Posting Raw HTML, same code works in other framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, encoding

I have some JS in an old framework that dynamically posts form data to the backend, and then backend converts the posted HTML to a PDF document that can be displayed inline or downloaded.  Those are basically buttons the have the element id wrapping the content (HTML to be converted to PDF) in the data-content attribute.  data-css in just a short name for any custom css, data-filename is the name and data-disposition is attachment or download, etc.

```
$("body").on("click", ".wkdownload", function(e) {

        dynamicPostForm ('/Utilities/getPDFfromBody', {markup: $($(this).data("content"))[0].outerHTML, extra: $(this).data("css"), filename:  $(this).data("filename"), disposition: "attachment"}, false);

});

$("body").on("click", ".wknewtab", function(e) {

        dynamicPostForm ('/Utilities/getPDFfromBody', {markup: $($(this).data("content"))[0].outerHTML, extra: $(this).data("css"), filename:  $(this).data("filename"), disposition: "inline"}, true);
});
```

There is another function that dynamically creates, submits and destroys a form after posting it:

```
function dynamicPostForm (path, params, target) {

    method = "post";
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    if (target) {
        form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    }
    for(var key in params) {

        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "_token");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", '{{ csrf_token() }}');
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    $(form).remove();
}
```

This all seems to work in the old framework, but in the new framework there is an issue with the "markup" input field getting truncated from some reason.  I thought it might be on the backend, but it seems to be on the client side based on what I am logging in the console.

In the new framework, the attribute is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="markup" value="<div id=">
```

whereas in the old framework it is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="markup" value="<div id=\"reportnoheader . . . al message.</div></div>"
```

But the code is basically the same in both.  Not that the " is not escaped in the first instance, whereas it is escaped in the second instance.

and when I check the post in the console, I see the same, old:

markup is:

```
<div+id="reportnoheader"> . . . .</div>"
```

and in the new:

```
"<div+id=" (truncated).
```

Not sure why that is since the code is almost exactly the same.  I could play around with escaping or encoding, but it works fine in the old framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be answering my own question, but simply using .value = value instead of setAttributute("value", params[key]) seems to fix the problem for me:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {

    if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.value = value;
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
     }
}
```

Comment: Not really clear to me why it works in the old framework using the hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);, whereas I have to use value in the new framework.  Same Browser.  Must have something to do with an environment setup ?  The new Framework is Laravel that has jQuery, Bootstrap, Alpine and some other stuff installed.